# how to extract text and image both indivitually from HTML body using JQuery

Tags: jquery, extract

I have HTML Body. I want to extract text and Image. And then I want to send src of image with text to another php page using:

```
$.post("sendtextandimage.php","task=sendmsg"+"&text="+text+"img="+src,
  function(data) {

});  or $.ajax();
```

My HTML body is given below:

`<div>Image src url with Title:PHP championCity:Mumbai, Maharashtra, IndiaSummary:We are looking for a PHP champ for our Mumbai office. Candidate with knowledge of mobile app development will be given added advantage.</div>`

How to fix it.
I need your hand.
Thank you

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you had a sample of html and could show exactly what you want to get out of it. jQuery has a method called .text() that will get you the text out of an element, but that is usually messy. A better example would help get a better answer.

Comment: Could explain this in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('div#id1').text();
var src = $('img#id2').attr('src');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.But how to extract multiple images with Text i.e, text, imgsrc1, imgsrc2, and so on.And I also wanna send multiple imgsrc with text to another php page.

Comment: If you include more of your HTML I´ll see what I can do for you.